# In Zend Studio, how do I limit Controllers and Models in the MVC Outline to just those I have created?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, zend-studio

In the MVC Outline tab of Zend Studio, several Models and Controllers are listed that I have not created. For example, the `Zend_Rest_Controller` shows up with the path `\MyProjectName\library\Rest\Controller.php`.

Does anyone know how to ignore these Models and Controllers? Thank you,

Comment: What Zend Studio version are you using? It is indeed a weird behaviour, have never observed it.

Comment: I'm using version 8, the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing the properties of the library folder in Zend Studio and mark it as derived.